# Extracting failed columns from Deepchecks

Tags: suite, drift

How can I extract from Deepcheck's custom suite result the failed checks + exact "problematic" columns.
In my example I had 2 failed checks 'Feature Drift' & 'Multivariate Drift'.
For both checks the "problematic" columns were 'col_1' , 'col_5' and 'col_30'.

How using Python I can get something like this :

1. Check 'Feature Drift' was failed because of : 'col_1' (Drift score = 0.9) , 'col_5'(Drift score = 0.7)
2. Check 'Multivariate Drift' was failed because of : 'col_1' and  'col_30'  with domain_classifier_drift_score = 0.85

My code is :

```
columns_metadata = {'cat_features' : categorical_cols, 'label':y_label_col } 
train_dataset = Dataset(df = train_df   , **columns_metadata)
test_dataset  = Dataset(df = test_df    , **columns_metadata )

custom_drift_suite = Suite('My_custom_drift_suite',
                         FeatureDrift().add_condition_drift_score_less_than( max_allowed_categorical_score=0.2, max_allowed_numeric_score=0.2),
                        at a time (can’t be recognized with Feature Drift)
                         MultivariateDrift().add_condition_overall_drift_value_less_than(0.4), 
                         LabelDrift(),
                         NewCategoryTrainTest()train set ) 
                            
                        )
custom_suite_ans = custom_drift_suite.run(train_dataset = train_dataset, test_dataset = test_dataset)
```

Thanks :)
Boris

Answer (score 0):

The suite result contains check results which contain conditions results.
The following code will print the conditions results:

```
import deepchecks 

for check_result in custom_suite_ans.get_not_passed_checks():
    for condition in check_result.conditions_results:
        print(condition.name + ': ' + condition.details)
        # Access the result of the check - can get columns, etc
        print(check_result.value)
```

Comment: check_result.value has different format per check . I.e FeatureDrift() & MultivariateDrift() tests returns different formats. is there a way to write function that will return problematic  column per each check ? without the need to have extraction function per each check  type.

Comment: And for failed check I assume that 'custom_suite_ans.get_not_passed_checks()' cab be used. The question how to filter from there only the failed columns and their score

Comment: yes you can use `custom_suite_ans.get_not_passed_checks`, simplified my answer. About the format, there isn't an easier way currently, the solution in my opinion would be to have a standardized format. Please open an issue in deepchecks' GitHub describing your need

Comment: Thanks ! created new issue in Git as you suggested :  https://github.com/deepchecks/deepchecks/issues/2416